# input field value on keyup but also can be manual input

Tags: jquery, keyup

I have a total of 6 input fields like

```
<input type="text" name="count500" id="count500" value="">
<input type="text" name="count200" id="count200" value="">
<input type="text" name="count100" id="count100" value="">
<input type="text" name="count50" id="count50" value="">
<input type="text" name="count10" id="count10" value="">
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="">
```

On each of the first five's input field values, on keyup, the total is instanly shown on the "total" input field.

```
<script>
  function doTotal() {
    count500 = parseFloat($("#count500").val() * 500) || 0;
    count200 = parseFloat($("#count200").val() * 200) || 0;
    count100 = parseFloat($("#count100").val() * 100) || 0;
    count50 = parseFloat($("#count50").val() * 50) || 0;
    count10 = parseFloat($("#count10").val() * 10) || 0;
    total = count500 + count200 + count100 + count50 + count10;
    $("#totak").val(nc.toFixed(2));
  }

$('input').keyup(function() {
  doTotal();        
}); 
</script>
```

That is working well without an issue.

But I also like the ability for the user to manually type in a value in total. Currently anything that's typed into it disappears,

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can i give you some short technique to this more easier??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class `inputValues` to the input element other than the total. By adding the class you are excluding the input field for the toltal.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="count500" class="inputValues" id="count500" value="">
<input type="text" name="count200" class="inputValues" id="count200" value="">
<input type="text" name="count100" class="inputValues" id="count100" value="">
<input type="text" name="count50" class="inputValues" id="count50" value="">
<input type="text" name="count10" class="inputValues" id="count10" value="">
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="">
```

**jQuery**

```
function doTotal() {
  count500 = parseFloat($("#count500").val() * 500) || 0;
  count200 = parseFloat($("#count200").val() * 200) || 0;
  count100 = parseFloat($("#count100").val() * 100) || 0;
  count50 = parseFloat($("#count50").val() * 50) || 0;
  count10 = parseFloat($("#count10").val() * 10) || 0;
  total = count500 + count200 + count100 + count50 + count10;
  $("#totak").val(nc.toFixed(2));
}
$('input.inputValues').keyup(function() {
  doTotal();        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is other solution of your problem, if you need then you can use.

Here is the short way how you can reach/ achieve your destination.

**Modified HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="count500" class="count counter" data-multi= "500" value="">
<input type="text" name="count200" class="count counter" data-multi= "200" value="">
<input type="text" name="count100" class="count counter" data-multi= "100" value="">
<input type="text" name="count50"  class="count counter" data-multi= "50" value="">
<input type="text" name="count10"  class="count counter" data-multi= "10" value="">
<input type="text" name="total" class="doTotal" value="">
```

**New jQuery:**

```
$(".count").on("keyup", function(){
    var doTotal = 0;
    $(".counter").each(function(){
        var multiplyer = $(this).attr("data-multi");
        doTotal += parseFloat($(this).val() * multiplyer) || 0;
    });
    $(".doTotal").val(doTotal.toFixed(2));
});
```

If you get help then let me know.